# Creating software raid on spare internal drives with Fedora

Tags: linux, raid, fedora

I got two internal 80GB drives which are blank and just sitting in the case. I have tried googling for the steps or some info but I can only find out how to setup raid when I am first installing Fedora - not for doing when already setup.

These are two new (old) drives, that are blank, the system is not on them so should really just be as simple as formating and then binding them to a raid - but can't find any information.

Any clues?

Comment: Which version of Fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=171091 or

contain the steps to configure software RAID1.

1. partition the disks
2. create an "md" device (mdadm) - probably /dev/md0 - using the appropriate RAID level
3. put a filesystem on the device, mount it and use it